# How to sort dataframes within a list by column value within each dataframe?

Tags: r

I am trying to rank machines (dataframes) by their machine score (column) and sort them from lowest to highest. Each machine is an element within a list. So I have a list of 281 dataframes, all of which contain a column titled `Machine Score`.

I've attempted many times to code up a function but always get stuck up on the actual sorting of the elements in the list.

```
mach1 <- data.frame('A' = 1:3, 'B' = 1:3, 'C' = .5)
mach2 <- data.frame('A' = 1:4, 'B' = 2:5, 'C' = .2)
mach3 <- data.frame('A' = 1, 'B' = 2, 'C' = .9)

list <- list(mach1,mach2,mach3)
```

What I would like to do, is have my list elements sorted so they appear in the order:

```
 list(mach2,mach1,mach3)
```

so the dataframe with the lowest value in column C appears first and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R option would be to extract the `min` value from `list` and `order` it

```
out <- list[order( sapply(list, function(x) min(x$C)))]
out
#[[1]]
#  A B   C
#1 1 2 0.2
#2 2 3 0.2
#3 3 4 0.2
#4 4 5 0.2

#[[2]]
#  A B   C
#1 1 1 0.5
#2 2 2 0.5
#3 3 3 0.5

#[[3]]
#  A B   C
#1 1 2 0.9
```

NOTE: `list` is a function, so it is better not to name the identifier object with the function name

Comment: Your note proved to be instant karma; I couldn't run your code because I was using list as the function rather than my list name. Thank you for the help!